# Error inputText

Tags: android

Hola todos error del log sobre un inputText, nose como eliminar, la app corre pero a cierto momento se cierra, este me sale en el log.

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Saludos

ACTUALIZACION.
El problema es un inputtext desde un Alerdialog, así lo declaro.

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    input.setHint("0.000");
    builder.setView(input).setTitle("Ingrese Cantidad");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: Añade algo más de información, como el código o el xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a tu `EditText` la propiedad:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

o programaticamente:

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```